# Linear model with a categorical variable with multiple levels

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data

Basic regression model question.

Suppose I treated 3 groups of mice, group 1 with water, group 2 with drug A, and group 3 with drug B. The water treatment thus serves as baseline.

Now my question is what is a more appropriate linear model to use in order to assess the effect of each drug relative to the water treatment:

1. Do 2 pairwise comparisons: A vs. water and B vs. water?
2. Use a linear model: `response ~ treatment`, where the levels in `treatment` are: water, A, and B with dummy coding.

Answer (score 1):

I'd sort of use a mix of the two options you have suggested. I'd fit the linear model `response ~ treatment` where `treatment` is at three levels. (note that if you are working in R then dummy coding is automated). Since you have a specific hypothesis in mind, I would also set *a priori* contrasts on the linear model to test whether `water = a` and `water = b`. Again, if you are working in R then setting contrasts like this is fairly straightforward.

Comment: So I guess by running a linear model as response ~ treatment in R, it is actually doing all pairwise contrasts vs. the baseline level, correct?

Comment: Yep, R uses the constraint of reference level set to zero. As long as water is your reference level then it will test the others against that